# Tomcat Context - server.xml - how to serve static files from network location folder

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm Running projects on a localhost `Tomcat` container, since the resource folder (images) are located on a network location folder (server reachable in my current network), I was wondering if it's possible to include this as a Tomcat docBase on the `server.xml` configuration file.

As the live environments are mounted under 1 host, I'm seeking a solution for localhost 'quick' testing.

Till now I have always been serving static content (including web pages) from outside of the 'WAR' using the Apache docBase tag (but these were locations on the same 'drive'):

```
<Context docBase="[ip]/folder" path="/files" />
```

Can anybody point me in a direction in serving static content from another host [ip] (network reachable location)?

I know there are other implementations as serving the contents through a servlet, but if possible I want to prevent servlets serving resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize this is not good for performance right? To serve those resources from the one tomcat instance it would first have to be pulled over the internal network and then pushed to the client. It'd be better to serve those external resources using an external HTTPD server running on the same host as the external resources.

Comment: @Gimby - +1 with your comment - this is just for quick localhost 'testing'. Our live environments are all mounted under 1 host :).

Comment: Fair enough - its worth it to add such contextual details to the question. It helps to determine what kind of solutions are viable answers - if its only for local testing any quick hack will do.

Comment: Thanks for your critique! Updated the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can mount that remote location here and serve those files as if they are files on this machine.